# Почему не срабатывает метод NinjectModule.Load()

Tags: asp.net

Вот я вызываю конструктор объекта NinjectModule

```
    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var modules = new INinjectModule[] { new ServiceMod("DefaultConnectionTest") };
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        try
        {
            kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
            kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

            RegisterServices(kernel);
            return kernel;
        }
        catch
        {
            kernel.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Вот реализация класса наследует NinjectModule:

```
    public class ServiceMod : NinjectModule
{
    private string p;

    public ServiceMod(string p)
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
        this.p = p;
    }
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IUnitofWork>().To<UnitofWork>().WithConstructorArgument(p);
    }
}
```

И проблема в добавлении зависимости т.к. метод Load() не срабатывает!!!
Помогите с этим вопросом. Пожалуйста.